# Creating a Simple form using django. Stuck between two error, Attribute Error and Key error

Tags: python, django

This is my form code and I am getting error an Keyerror on line 8 and 9 i.e name and also email.I am also getting attribute error on line with ValidationError.

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ValidationError

class StudentRegistration(forms.Form):
    name= forms.CharField()
    email= forms.EmailField()
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        valname= self.cleaned_data ['name'] 
        valemail=self.cleaned_data [ 'email'] 
        if len(valname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidatonError('Name should be more than or equal to 4')
        if len(valemail) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidatonError('Abe dhang se daal')
```

My Error:

```
AttributeError at /regi/registration/
module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'ValidatonError'\
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/regi/registration/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'ValidatonError'
Exception Location: C:\Users\pkish\OneDrive\Desktop\GS\gs41\enroll\forms.py in clean, line 11
Python Executable:  C:\Users\pkish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\pkish\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\GS\\gs41',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\pkish\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\confusable_homoglyphs-3.2.0-py3.8.egg']
Server time:    Sun, 28 Mar 2021 15:42:39 +0000
```

Comment: It's `ValidationError` not `ValidatonError` (notice the `i`).

Comment: Oh my, can't  help but slap myself.